# two tables side by side

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am new to css. I want to put two tables side by side. This is what I got.(Using bootstrap) [image: two tables]

I want to position the 'Pizza's' table at the middle of the page. I want the other table right side of the 'Pizza's' table.

My css:

```
.table2{

  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.table2 td{
  padding: 2px;
}

.table2 th{
  background-color: #d9534f;
  padding: 2px;
}

.table3{
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.table3 td{
  padding: 2px;
}

.table3 th{
padding: 2px;
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="table2">
  <h2>Table</h2>

  <div class="table-borderless">          
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Pizza's</th>
        <th>-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Margharita</td>
        <td> $7.00 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table3" >
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Totaal</th>
        <th>-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Margharita</td>
        <td> $7.00 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I succeed when I float one to left and other to right, but that is not what I want. I tried this also:

```
.table3{
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You want to tell both of the wrappers to be `inline-block`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mb7t309/2/)

```
.table2, .table3 {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Table Totaal is not above table Pizza's. But on the JS Fiddle, I see it correctly...

Comment: I mean, at the page I am hosting, I don't see them side by side. But at JS Fiddle, I see them side by side

Comment: You have to add that CSS to it that I gave you. It's also possible you have other structure/code that you did not provide that could be causing issues. I can only help you with what I have available.

Comment: The Pizza's table is not centered as I wanted. This is partly my answer. It is floating to the left side.

Comment: I want the pizza's table centered and the totaal table right side of it. But when I use inline-block, it is automatically floating to left

Comment: I updated the fiddle with an example for your current structure. Its not the greatest method, but for current code it works.

Comment: Your using bootstrap but I do not see you using it's positioning tags? I.e col-md-4 as a class on you divs containing your tables would fix this